# onLoad is not working for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to trigger an action as soon as an element on the page is loaded. I am using Jquery's `on('load')` functionality to do this.

However it is not working. Here is the code and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79hqorrn/)

```
console.log("Hi");
$('#complexDiv').on('load', function(){
    console.log('Header loaded');
});
```

HTML

```
</header>
<body>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <div id="complexDiv">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe load event is only called on elements that require external resources.

**From jQuery:**

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

**Case for .ready():**

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed and you can use .ready() for that.

For your situation you can listen to window load or better yet use ready because load is deprecated.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    console.log('Header loaded');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `animation` property at `css` for `#complexDiv` element with `animation-duration` set to `0s`, use `animationstart` event attached to `$(window)`, `.one()`.

Note, `onanimationstart` event attribute can be used at chrome, chromium without jQuery `.one()`; firefox 47 did not recognize `onanimationstart` event attirbute. Also, `@keyframes` should be set for `animation-name` at `css`, though not properties are required to be set.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    #complexDiv {
      animation: e 0s;
      -moz-animation: e 0s;
      -webkit-animation: e 0s;
    }        
    @keyframes e {}       
    @-moz-keyframes e {}        
    @-webkit-keyframes e {}
  </style>
  <script>
    $(window).one("animationstart", function(e) {
      alert(e.target.id + " " + e.type)
      console.log(e.target, e.type);
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <div id="complexDiv">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
    <img alt="" src="" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/70FF4AyY9URLnwgIZl68?p=preview